# Is this tail recursion and why?

Tags: python, recursion

Trying to teach my brain to spot head vs tail recursion. Is this tail recursion ? The recursive statement is at the end , but there is some data being stored in the total variable too, so that got me confused.

```py
def visible_tree_node(root:Node) -> int:
    def dfs(root:Node,current_max:int) -> int:
        if not root:
            return 0
        total = 0
        if root.val >= current_max:
            current_max = root.val
            total +=1
        total += dfs(root.left,current_max)
        total += dfs(root.right,current_max)

        return total

    return dfs(root,-float('inf'))
```

Comment: There are multiple calls to dfs within dfs that are not a single call at the end.

Comment: (not being a compiler expert) I'd go with *no*, because you have two branches. The right branch might be able to optimize for tail recursion, though, because it can be run as `return total + dfs(root.right, current_max)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dfs` call in `visible_tree_node` is in tail position. That call, and *only* that call, could have its stack frame omitted via [tail call elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). Note that, according to that same Wikipedia page, CPython does not do tail call elimination anyway.

The recursive `dfs` calls in the `dfs` function itself are not in tail position. Nontrivial work happens after each of them (namely, a call to `+=`, which at best is a simple addition and assignment and at worst calls an arbitrary magic method on some object).

The exact rules for tail position are sometimes complicated. The very short version is: A call is in tail position if the function does no more work after that call. Where the complexity comes in is what "work" means. For instance, the call can be preceded by `return`, and that's fine. But having it be an argument to `+` makes it no longer in tail position.

Tail position is usually defined in terms of a [control flow graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-flow_graph). In a CFG, your code doesn't have things like `if` statements and `for` loops. It's a directed (potentially cyclic) graph where each node in the graph consists of ordinary, linear code (assignments, arithmetic operations, but *not* any kind of branching), and each block ends in an instruction that informs the code of which block to enter next, either unconditionally or (more commonly) by branching based on some condition.

So, for example,

```
a
if b:
  c
else:
  d
e
```

would compile to a block `a`, which conditionally jumps (based on `b`) to either of two blocks `c` or `d`. Both blocks `c` and `d` jump unconditionally to `e` at the end.

[image: CFG for if statement]

Similarly, a `while` loop will compile to a block which has a conditional jump at the end. The conditional jump will go *backwards* to the start of the loop if some condition is true and onward if false.

```
a
while b:
  c
d
```

[image: CFG for while statement]

In CFG form, a call is in tail position if it is at the very end of the function. We can recursively define those rules in terms of Python constructs as follows. I'm most familiar with [static single-assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single-assignment_form), so I'll use that in the examples below.

- The very last line of a function is in tail position, since there are no instructions after it.
- The expression of a `return` statement in tail position is itself in tail position, for similar reasons.
- If an `if` statement is in tail position, then the last line of the `if` branch, as well as any `elif` or `else` branches, are all in tail position. An `if` (and `else` and `elif`) causes the CFG to split, and if it's in tail position then the split won't come back together; it'll simply return to the caller, so as far as CFG analysis is concerned, we're still at the end of the function.
- If a loop (`for` or `while`) is in tail position, then any statement immediately succeeded by a `break` inside this loop is in tail position. This one is complicated, so some optimizers may miss it. A `break` inside a loop would compile in SSA to a `goto` the end of the loop, and if the end of the loop is also the end of the function (i.e. tail position), then the thing right before the `break` is as well.
- If a `try ... finally` block appears in tail position, then the last line of the `finally` portion is also in tail position.

Some constructs are never in tail position. For example, the inside of a `with` is never in tail position, because `with` has to run code after the block is done. These rules are not comprehensive; they're just what I could come up with right now on the spot based on how the various Python constructs compile to CFG. A comprehensive list would require a more detailed analysis of control flow that wouldn't fit in the scope of this answer.

I've never heard the term "head recursion" before. I suppose it could be defined to mean "the recursion is the very first thing" by rules basically dual to those above, but it doesn't sound like a very useful concept (since it would be impossible to optimize around).